# What type of adhesive should i use for installing tile board to glazed tile?

Tags: bathroom

I have glazed tile around my tub and almost all of them or cracked or chiped,So without haveing to replace the tile i am putting up decrative tile board and i don't know what type of  adhesive to use the tile board is tile like on the front and a hard board on the back.Any idea of what i could use to adhere this board to my tile with??

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use thinset?

Comment: I did'nt know if thinset would bond to the smooth surface of the glazed tile in order to adhere my tileboard..

Comment: [liquid nails](http://www.liquidnails.com/tips/paneling-tileboard) has a good run down on installing wallboard. Don't use thinset. Sand the tile.